# Danish fantasy book with a small travelling man and a warrior named Mira who meets a minotaur

Tags: story-identification, books, elves

I read this book around 15 years ago, in Danish (possibly by a Danish author, but maybe just a translation). It might be a single book or a series.

It is a fantasy book, following several character lines.
I specifically remember a character called Mira. She is not there from the beginning, but enters the story quite late. She was some kind of warrior, and she meets a minotaur. They are involved in some kind of war.

There are many species represented, of course including elves. In one of the storylines I remember a clan of elves "protected" by some kind of magical sphere, but it is starting to strangle the land. And I think the elf prince (or something, I remember he was unusually loud and clumsy for an elf?) set off from the land. I don't know where he was going, but he had the wind on his left cheek.

My absolute favorite character line was the one with the small man. He wasn't a hobbit, but a species I never heard of before. He had a strange name and just a wonderful cheerful character. Only thing I remember was that he was a traveler, traveling by foot, bumping into other characters during the story. There may have been some kind of magical travel going on here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This matches some of the elements of Tad Williams's _Memory, Sorrow, and Thorn_ trilogy.

Comment: @Spencer: The only Tad Williams' books that have been translated into Danish are the first two *Otherland* books. (I know, because I translated 'em.)

Comment: Josefine Ottesen has a trilogy about a girl named Mira. Might that be it? https://historienommira.dk/josefineottesen/?B%F8ger:Fantastiske_fort%E6llinger:Historien_om_Mira

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Dragons of a Fallen Sun](https://archive.org/details/dragonsoffallens00weis), by American authors Margaret Weis (pronounced "wise", spelled "Weiss" on the cover of the printed Danish edition) and Tracy Hickman.

It was published in Danish in two volumes titled *Dragernes tid* and *Elvernes land* and is part of the *War of Souls* (translated alternatively as *Sjælekrigen* or *Sjæle-krøniken*) series.

The young woman is named Mina. She appears frequently through the book starting from Chapter 1, in which she meets a minotaur.

There are elves in the book, two elf kingdoms, and two elf princes.

The elf kingdom of Silvanesti is secretly ruled by an evil dragon and is protected by a magical shield which sucks life out of the land. The weak-willed elf prince Silvanoshei, an heir to both kingdoms, makes his way into Silvanesti through the shield and is made a puppet king.

In contrast, the elf kingdom of Qualinesti is *openly* ruled by an evil dragon, and also by its puppet king Gilthas, who is secretly competent and planning to overthrow draconic occupation.

The small man is Tasslehoff Burrfoot. He is a kender (plural *kender*), which is a fictional humanoid race unique to the Dragonlance setting. Kender are cheerful and fond of traveling. Tasslehoff is brought to the world from its past by the Device of Time Journeying. There are many more *Dragonlance* books featuring Tasslehoff as a protagonist, most notably the *Chronicles* and *Legends* trilogies, each book of which was likewise split into two volumes in Danish.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That is (obviously) it! Did not think I would get the correct answer, I am really impressed!

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Dave Duncan's *[King of Swords](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18710801-king-of-swords)*?

> Rigel has always known he is not quite human, but the only clue to his origin is the otherworldly bracelet he has worn since childhood.
>
> His search for his parentage leads him to the Starlands, where reality and fantasy have changed places. There he learns that he is a human-starborn cross, and his bracelet is the legendary magical amulet Saiph, which makes its wearer an unbeatable swordsman. Fighting off monsters, battling a gang of assassins seeking to kill him, Rigel finds honorable employment as a hero. He knows that he must die very soon if he remains in the Starlands, but he has fallen hopelessly in love with a princess and cannot abandon her.
>
> Through the imaginative landscape of the Starlands, Rigel's quest leads him to encounter minotaurs, sphinxes, cyclops, and more fearsome creatures in Dave Duncan's latest fantasy series.

It does include an oddly named small man, [a woman named Mira](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1910523077?book_show_action=true), and minotaurs. Not matching, the oldest copy I can find is from 2015 and I do not see a Danish translation.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I also found it while googling, but it is not it :(

Comment: @Lot: I don't suppose you can point out particular areas, other than the publication date and lack of Danish translation, where it's different? :)

Comment: I have the book King of Swords and there are significant differences from the description. The main protagonist, Rigel, is not a small man. He is described as "lanky". Mira is not a warrior and she meets Rigel right at the beginning of the novel when she helps him after he is attacked by a bear, not "quite late" in the story. I couldn't find any mention of a magic sphere protecting elves.